# AngularJs-Adding pagination to dynamic rows with in table

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, pagination

Need to add pagination while generating dynamic tr through directive

[image]

In the picture above, the **green** boxes are dynamically generated on click with directive template:

```js
template:'<tr ng-repeat="result in results" ng-class="{ \'fa-slide-up\': !showMe, \'fa-slide-down\': showMe }" ><div ><td ng-click="openDialog(result)" id="greenBackground"> {{result}} </td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td id="greenBackground"></td><td id="greenBackground"></td><td id="greenBackground"></td><td id="greenBackground"></td></div></tr>',
```

I tried adding simplePagination.js and dirPagination.js but it's not even showing the dynamic rows need help on this

Comment: Can u pls share fiddle ?

Answer (score 0):

Hi it is all because of JS loading order. You might have loading the content dynamically in the doc.ready() and the API would be executed before the dom is ready. In this case call you pagination JS at end of dom creation

Sample : 
place your pagination API call statements inside app.controller . and call is same at the end of DOM load as below

```
$scope.callUpdate = function() {
          // your pagination API calls go here instead of below treegrid sample
             $('.tree').treegrid({
                initialState : 'collapsed'
            });
        };
```

-

```
<table class="tree">
    <tr class="treegrid-{{valu.self}} treegrid-parent-{{valuation.parent}} " ng-repeat="valu in valuation">
      <td>{{ valu.percentage.toFixed(2) }}</td>
      <td>{{ valu.percentage.toFixed(2) }}</td>
    </tr>
    <span>{{callUpdate()}}</span>
  </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

To add pagination i use this js library.

[Ng-Table](http://ng-table.com/#/)

and add this to my table

```
<table class="table table-bordered" ng-table="tableParams">
```

Main:

```
var miApp = angular.module('Clinica', ['ngRoute', 'ngTable', 'ngCookies']);
```

Controller:

```
miApp.controller('profesionalController', ['$scope', 'profesionalService', '$rootScope', 'ngTableParams', function ($scope, profesionalService, $rootScope, ngTableParams) {

profesionalService.getClinic().then(function (datos) {
            $scope.profesionals = datos;
            var data = $scope.profesionals;
            $scope.tableParams = new ngTableParams({
                page: 1, // show first page
                count: 3           // count per page        
            }, {
                total: data.length, // length of data
                getData: function ($defer, params) {                    
                    data = $scope.profesionales;                   
                    params.total(data.length);                    
                    if (params.total() <= ((params.page() - 1) * params.count())) {
                        params.page(1);
                    }                    
                    $defer.resolve(data.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count()));
                }
            });
        });
}]);
```